# Edição de nome é confirmada no banco de dados mas não acontece na listagem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Estou editando uma coluna do banco de dados e até ai tudo ocorre muito bem, porém quando vou carregar a tabela que contem esta coluna usando o Include, simplesmente não atualiza o "**Motorista**", troca o ID no relacionamento porém na listagem continua o nome do antigo cadastrado (na verdade o que foi cadastrado nunca troca).

Segue a consulta:

```
return View(context.Veiculos.Include(v => v.Motorista).Where(v => v.EmpresaID == userId && !v.Excluido).OrderByDescending(c => c.Ano).ToList());
```

No banco de dados as duas colunas da listagem estão com o mesmo motorista, segue o print que comprova:

[image: banco de dados]

Aqui mostra como realmente o motorista não esta sendo carregado corretamente:

[image: listagem]

Segue o código das referências entre as duas Models:

Classe do Usuário:

```
[Display(Name = "Vehicles", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
public virtual ICollection<Veiculo> VeiculosEmpresa { get; set; }
```

Classe do Veículo:

```
[Required]
public Guid MotoristaID { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Driver", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
public virtual ApplicationUser Motorista { get; set; }
```

ModelBuilder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Veiculo>().HasRequired(x => x.Motorista).WithMany(x => x.VeiculosMotorista);
modelBuilder.Entity<Veiculo>().HasRequired(x => x.Empresa).WithMany(x => x.VeiculosEmpresa);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por padrão, as consultas ficam em cache para cada instância de contexto.

Mesmo que você grave dados no contexto com SaveChanges o dado o cache é mantido para aquela instância de contexto.

Há algumas formas de ter o dado atualizado.

**1- Finalizar o contexto:**

O que mais uso é dar dispose no meu contexto logo após usá-lo.
Geralmente coloco meu objeto contexto em um bloco `using`:

```
using (MeuContextoEntities context = new MeuContextoEntities())
{
    //minhas operações com o contexto.
}
```

2 - Se você estiver usando um objeto de contexto global (que não recomendo), você pode usar o método **[Refresh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255.aspx)** do objeto contexto para atualizá-lo com dados vindos do banco.

```
context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, seuObjetoEntity);
```